# Simple JS calculation issue

Tags: javascript

I made a simple html with an input and h1

```
<body>
  <input type="number" name="number">
  <h1>Result</h1>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="kalantzakisCalculator.js"> 
  </script>
</body>
```

And a simple calculation .

```
const val = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(val) {
 let result = val + (val * 0.2);
 h1.textContent = result;   
});
```

The calculation is not showing properly on h1....

Comment: _The calculation is not showing properly on h1...._ What would be properly in your expectations?

Comment: I want to show the "result" variable on h1

Answer (score 0):

When the callback function is invoked by the event (`click`) the outside code of the function is not executed, only the code inside the function is executed.

Declare variable `val` inside the function:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const val = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
  let result = val + (val * 0.2);
  h1.textContent = result;   
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="number">
<h1>Result</h1>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Works fine thank you.
But why the callback function can't get the global variable ?

Comment: @D.Tsiridakis, when the callback function is invoked the outside code of the function is not executed....only the code inside the function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The **val** parameter is a MouseEvent interface object of the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event.

I've renamed (val to inputNumber) and moved it inside addEventListener.
Working code below:

```
<body>
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
        const button = document.querySelector('button');

        // >>val<< is a MouseEvent
        button.addEventListener('click', function(val) { 
            let inputNumber = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
            let result = inputNumber + (inputNumber * 0.2);

            h1.textContent = result;   
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Tip:** In Chrome, use F12 for [Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).